In writing a custom Camera shader in Unity (Shaderlab), how do I color each point in the captured image to be the color of the original 3D point?
I'm writing a Camera shader for Unity, which I'm rendering on a Camera using Camera.SetReplacementShader. I've currently defined a vertex and fragment shader, which serves to emulate a real-world camera. That is, I'm not using the orthographic/perspective projection matrices, but rather, I'm doing some custom projection logic.
The issue is that because I need the Camera to behave like a real-world camera, I don't really know how to color the pixels (ie. assign them an RGBA color). I essentially want my shader to shade each output vertex o as the same color as the color of the 3D pixel v (that o represents) as shown in the scene. This is what the default Camera object in Unity seems to do. But I have no idea how to emulate this, and I can't seem to find the answer to this online.
I'm currently shading each pixel using the _MainTex texture, which doesn't work. (This is expected, since I don't want to sample the color based on a texture, but rather the actual color of the pixel in the scene.) I'm not sure if this is relevant, but I am manually setting the main texture to a custom texture in a script.
How can I go about achieving this? (Thanks in advance!)
This is a simplified version of the current shader code I have:
Shader "Custom/IntrinsicCalibration" {
    Properties {
        _MainTex ("Texture", 2D) = "white" {}
    }
    SubShader {
        Tags { "RenderType"="Opaque" }
        LOD 100

        PASS {
            CGPROGRAM
            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag
            #include "UnityCG.cginc"

            struct appdata {
                float4 vertex : POSITION;
                float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
            };

            struct v2f {
                float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
                float4 vertex : SV_POSITION;
            };

            sampler2D _MainTex;
            float4 _MainTex_ST;

            // v refers to the view vertex in model space
            v2f vert (appdata v) {
                v2f o;

                float3 viewSpaceVertex = UnityObjectToViewPos(v.vertex.xyz); // view space analogue to camera coordinate space
                o.vertex = ...; // does irrelevant custom projection stuff with viewSpaceVertex
                o.uv = TRANSFORM_TEX(v.uv, _MainTex);
   
                return o;
            }

            fixed4 frag (v2f i) : SV_Target {
                return tex2D(_MainTex, i.uv); // this samples from _MainTex, not the scene!
            }
            ENDCG
        }
    }
}

